# A query gerada pelo Entity Framework é válida para usar em ADO?

Tags: entity-framework-6, ado.net

Estou querendo ter uma maior performance em uma consulta que realizo no sistema

Consequentemente usar `ADO` é muito mais rápido que `Entity Framework`

A `query` que ele gera ao realizar a consulta, poderia ser utilizada para criar uma `procedure` ou usar com `ADO`?

Ou é exatamente a `query` que ele gera que o torna lento ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A query que ele gera ao realizar a consulta, poderia ser utilizada para criar uma procedure ou usar com ADO?

Sim.

O problema é que ela está num formato muito mais conveniente para a manipulação pelo Entity Framework do que por uma lógica que você possa desenvolver.

## Ou é exatamente a query que ele gera que o torna lento?

Na verdade a *query* executa bem rápido. O problema é a transliteração de uma linha de resultado em um objeto.

Há uma série de regras que o Entity Framework utiliza para realizar esta tranformação, e há também uma série de técnicas para otimizar velocidade, como usar `Reflection` para gerar classes em tempo de execução e economizar tempo definindo objetos numa abordagem estática.

Há também a carga preguiçosa que faz este tempo aumentar consideravelmente, já que o Entity Framework precisa abrir uma conexão e executar uma consulta para cada entidade agregada da entidade original.

## Conclusão

[O Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) foi criado justamente pra resolver este problema de performance que você quer combater. Sugiro dar uma olhada ao invés de usar ADO.NET puro.